# Unable to run npm command "npm install -g tty.js".

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tty, adobe-brackets

```
***Unable to run npm command "npm install -g tty.js".
Here is the error log I am getting :***
```

=D:\Users\pjha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\ws

> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
>       D:\Users\pjha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\b
>       in\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
>   pty.js@0.3.1 install D:\Users\pjha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\pty.js
>   node-gyp rebuild
>       D:\Users\pjha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\pty.js>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-g
>       yp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
>       gyp ERR! configure error
>       gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
>       gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
>       gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
>       gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
>       gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
>       gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>       gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>       gyp ERR! cwd D:\Users\pjha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tty.js\node_modules\pty.js
>       gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.2
>       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
>       gyp ERR! not ok
>       D:\Users\pjha\AppData\Roaming\npm
>       `-- (empty)

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "tty.js"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pty.js@0.3.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pty.js@0.3.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pty.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pty.js
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:`enter code here`
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Praful\WorkSpaces\NodeJsWorkSpace\Test\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

See this issue on GitHub - #151: npm install pty.js` failed on Windows 10:

- https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/issues/151

And this - #54: can't install on windows:

- https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/issues/54

There are some solutions that people recommend. It's hard to tell which one will work for you but you should find some info in the comments to those issues.